# What resources do you use to find good color combinations?

Tags: resources, color-combination

My background is in web development, not UI design. I have no problem creating the layout and getting it pixel-perfect, but I can never figure out what colors to use and where. I have seen projects like Adobe's [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/), but even then I don't know where to apply the colors in the design. Which is a good background color? font color? accent color?

Where do you get your color combinations and how do you decide how to use them?

Comment: Similar question: http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/571/choosing-a-set-of-colors

Answer (score 20):

I use http://colorschemedesigner.com/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this web-app also help checking the color set against varying color blindness, quite useful

Answer (score 8):

[ColourLovers.com](http://colourlovers.com) is a great tool for this purpose and related.

Comment: +1 to this.  I always look there for inspiration.  And have recommended it whenever possible.

Comment: ColourLovers' parent company, Chromaom, also has http://www.colorschemer.com/, downloadable color matching software.

Answer (score 5):

I've used [ColorMatch](http://www.knorrpage.de/colormatch.html) in the past. You pick a colour you like and it will give you a six colour palette of complimentary colours based on the one you chose.

It is *very* lightweight, and because it is all done in html/javascript, can be saved to your disk for use when offline.

Answer (score 4):

As I posted in [Choosing a set of colors](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/571/choosing-a-set-of-colors), [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com) is an app by Adobe focused on creating and sharing color schemes. You can search for schemes by tag.

Answer (score 3):

[www.colorhunter.com](http://www.colorhunter.com/) builds color palettes based on images. You can upload an image or point it to a url and it will help you pick colors.

Also here is a site I built a few weeks ago. It is still in serious alpha but it lets you pick colors for various elements on a page and see them in live.

[ColorMoods](http://www.color-moods.com)

I would love any feed back you have about that. (remember alpha)

Comment: colorhunter is nice. at colormoods common schemes not working (color menu at left), also it's not obvious that user have to select element and then pick colors, everything else works well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Agave](http://home.gna.org/colorscheme/) occasionally for finding color combinations.

About "where to use them", I guess you need to experiment somewhat...?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some of the links under http://www.delicious.com/adrianh/colour of interest. It's a mix of tools and articles.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is the best: http://kuler.adobe.com

Answer (score -1):

http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorwizard.asp

It lets you pick a color as a starting point (or even randomize it) and then it gives you the supplemental colors with several different schemes (triadic, tetradic, complimentary, etc.)