# Choosing a set of colors

Tags: color, color-combination, graphic-design

I'm not a graphic designer, and I can't afford one for my open source project, so I thought I'd crowdsource this one. I'm trying to work out a set of 6-8 easily-differentiable colors for categories in my app. Here's what I have so far (and yeah, it sucks -- it's why I'm asking):

[image]

Choosing the obvious primary colors #FF0000, #00FF00, #0000FF, #FFFF00, #FF00FF, and #00FFFF looks jarring -- yes, they are easily differentiable, but at the price of being absolutely horrid.

Are there any resources on choosing a *set* of colors? There are many, many resources for choosing a color *scheme*, but these are at most 3 colors, some more "primary" than others.

Comment: I understand this is not the exact same question but you may want to look at the answers anyway.

http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-resources-do-you-use-to-find-good-color-combinations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for strong colors to differentiate categories I would suggest looking at other apps with the same functionality.

I don't think there is any IP issues with color palettes.

So for example here are the category colors from Outlook 2007

[image: Outlook 2007 Category Colors]

and here are the label colors from Gmail

[image: Google Label Colors]

Comment: Thanks; this is what I'll probably end up doing ;-P. Might steal the MS office app colors; each one has strong branding (word=blue, excel=green, infopath=purple) and there's a whole gradient for each rather than just one color

Comment: There *can* be IP issues with something as simple as a colour palette. The colour palette used by the seePOWER data visualization engine for heat-maps was **patented**. While Compudigm, the vendor I worked for, is now defunct, that patent is still around - it was one of Compudigms key pieces of IP.

Comment: You could also look at the gmail labels color palette or the google calendars color palette. Most of their default colors work well.

Answer (score 51):

Beyond just suggesting places like [Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/), [ColourLovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/copaso/ColorPaletteSoftware), [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/), [ColorMatch5K](http://www.knorrpage.de/colormatch.html) [ColorJack](http://www.colorjack.com/), and [ColorStream](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/17/color-stream-a-free-iphone-app-for-web-designers/) (iPhone app), you may benefit from learning about color theory and why and how colors should be combined and chosen. Here are some useful resources:

- [Worqx's Color Tutorials](http://www.worqx.com/color/index.htm)
- [Basic Color Theory](http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm)
- Smashing Magazine's 3-part series on
  color: [1](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/28/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/), [2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/02/color-theory-for-designers-part-2-understanding-concepts-and-terminology/), [3](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/08/color-theory-for-designer-part-3-creating-your-own-color-palettes/)
- [Luminance to Choose A Palette](http://visitmix.com/Opinions/Luminance-to-Choose-A-Palette)

Also relevant is the psychology and meanings behind choosing colors:

- [Visual Color Symbolism Chart by
  Culture](http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/bl_colorculture.htm)
- [Colors in Cultures Infographic](http://i.bnet.com/blogs/informationisbeautiful_955_colourscultures.png?tag=content;col1)
- [Color Psychology in Marketing](http://www.brandingstrategyinsider.com/2008/06/color-psycholog.html)
- [Why Color Matters](http://www.colormatters.com/market_whycolor.html) (check the
  left sidebar for more resources)

One other consideration is making sure that the colors work for colorblind users. See the following for more:

- [What is Colorblindness?](http://colorvisiontesting.com/color2.htm)
- [As Seen By The Colorblind](http://www.colourlovers.com/web/blog/2008/07/24/as-seen-by-the-color-blind)
  Popular websites, as seen by the
  colorblind. Also explains color
  blindness.
- [Effective Color Contrast: Designing for People with Partial Sight and Color Deficiencies](http://www.lighthouse.org/accessibility/design/accessible-print-design/effective-color-contrast)
- [Colorblind Web Page Filter](http://colorfilter.wickline.org/): Check your website or
  images to make sure they work for
  colorblindness.
- [Vischeck](http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/vischeckURL.php): Another URL and image checker - Also downloadable

To avoid information overload, for your project, I'd recommend something like the following workflow:

1. Write down a list of words and
   concepts that you want to describe
   your project, i.e. how you want it
   to be perceived. Examples would be:
   professional, edgy, soft,
   comforting, reliable, etc.
2. Look up 1-3 colors that represent
   some of the most important concepts
   you wish to convey.
3. Pay special attention to
   cross-cultural differences for color
   meanings when selecting your color
   or colors.
4. Use one of the classic color scheme
   types outlined in the resources
   above to choose your full color
   palette.
5. Stick to your color palette. If you
   add more colors, it can make your
   project seem just a little "off" or
   cluttered.
6. Test your color scheme by asking 3-5
   users in your target market to use your project or to look
   at screenshots and then write down
   how it makes them feel and what
   perceptions they gain about it, just
   by looking at it. Then compare the
   findings to your original word-list.
   Rework if necessary. Note that
   factors other than color like
   layout, copy, etc. may influence
   their list. To isolate the test users'
   feelings about the colors, present
   the color palette only.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I used a color theory cheat sheet that I have hung near my desk to come up with my answer....so why not teach a man to fish?  And props for providing a sample workflow also.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer like this for 2 years now! Thanks ;)

Comment: This is an excellent & complete answer. However, I'm not looking for a particular color palette for the app -- I'm trying to determine a set of 6-8 colors fro categories, each of equal importance.

Comment: What a ridiculously great answer. It makes my answer below quiver and shake in embarrassment at how inadequate it is.

Comment: +1 , brilliant answer and a wealth of good links .. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[Adobe's Kuler app](http://kuler.adobe.com/) is great for this.

Answer (score 1):

[colourlovers palettes](http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes) is a great resource for color palettes. Many if not most of them have ~5 colors.
Since you are choosing 6 colors, you could go for the tertiary colors, which are made by mixing a primary color with a secondary color. Yellow-orange, red-purple, red-orange, blue-green, blue-purple and yellow-green are tertiary colors. Check out this site: [Color Chart RGB](http://www.daleroose.com/web_design/color_chart/rgb/) to see a list of some of the different hues available along with their hex values. If you take a look at the column headings, you can see which columns are the tertiary colors.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I know what you need! You don't need to read theories and lots of articles!!!! you have a program, you want to choose colors for it! simple and easy. [here you can do that](http://www.colorschemer.com/studio_info.php).