# What are some recommended web resources for theming and design of WPF controls?

Tags: controls, wpf, themes

I previously tried to ask about themeing resources for WPF in this [previous question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/what-are-some-wpf-specific-design-resources-for-best-practise-in-themeing-control)
However at the time UI stack didn't really exist, and the SO guys gave "how to learn" type answer.

I'm looking for WPF specific link resources for themeing and design of WPF controls for both/either WPF and Silverlight.
Had a look at [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/ux-usability-resources-for-web) which gives generic design resources. Anyone able to provide a similiar list for the design and themeing of WPF controls?

Also looked at [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/resources-explaining-how-to-approach-ui-theming) which is the type of information which I guess would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

WPF is a way to implement an app, but UX resource doesn't exist s for it.

I think all the information included in the list of your link is useful in WPF. I can give you some Theming WPF links tough:

1. http://sachabarber.net/?p=354 ->
   Lookles Control
2. http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes
   -> WPF Themes in Codeplex
3. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx
   -> MSDN Styling

I don't know if it's what you expected, but if you looking for technical information, let me know.

Hope it helps,
Iban

Comment: yes this is what i was hoping for. Thanks iBenzal.